# How to correctly define and instantiate an inner class

Tags: java

I have defined a class that contains an inner class definition like this:-

```
public class A{
 public class B{
   }
}
```

However when I compile my code i do get an error from the compiler for this line:

```
 A.B innerObj=outerObj.new A.B();
```

What am I doing wrong ?

```
Error: A.java:9: error: ')' expected
          A.B innerObj=outerObj.new A.B();
                                     ^
```

Comment: What you are doing wrong: not posting the actual compiler error.

Comment: @luk2303, Please could you explain me above error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general syntax to create an instance of a member inner class is as follows:-

> OuterClassReference.new MemberInnerClassConstructor();

The new operator is already qualified with the enclosing instance reference (as in outerObj.new),
the java compiler will figure out the fully qualified name of the enclosing class name automatically.

Your code change should be:-

```
A.B innerObj=outerObj.new B();
```

Comment: THe alternative it to set the inner class beeing `static`, then the intended syntax works.

Comment: No even if you make the inner class as static, still his syntax i.e. A.B innerObj=outerObj.new A.B(); won't work.

Comment: If the inner class is static, it will be considered as top level class, and will not need instance of enclosing class for it's object creation. In that case, he can just do B innerObj=new B(); in class A.

Comment: @A *"If the inner class is static, it [...] will not need instance of enclosing class [...] In that case, he can just do B innerObj=new B(); "* Yes, but you could also write `A.B o = new A.B()` as the OP wanted...

Answer (score 1):

here is another way to create inner class instance,

```
// Instantiating the outer class
A outer = new A();

// Instantiating the inner class
A.B inner = outer.new B();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OuterClass {

class innerClass{
    void show(){
        System.out.println("this is a inner class");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {


    OuterClass oc=new OuterClass();
    OuterClass.innerClass ic=oc.new innerClass();
    ic.show();
}   }

//Output: this is a inner Class
```

You need Outer Class reference to instantiate the inner class